# Get selected value of a 2 dropdown items using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using the sql to retrieve the values for dropdown. I am only able to get only the 1st dropdownbox item. how do i get the second dropdown value. I am fetching the data from sql.

```
<label for="category">Category</label>
<select name="parent_cat" id="parent_cat">
    <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_parent)): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<label for="city">city</label>
<select name="city" id="city">
    <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_parent1)): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['city']; ?>"><?php echo $row['city']; ?></option>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</select>
<br/><br/>
```

and my jquery looks like below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#parent_cat").change(function(){
    var selectedCountry = $("option:selected").val(); 
      alert("You have selected the Country - " + selectedCountry);

});
});
```

I am able to get the 1st dropdown value how can i also get the second dropdown value

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#city").change(function(){
    var selectedCountry1 = $("option:selected").val(); 
      alert("You have selected the city- " + selectedCountry1);

});
});
```

Can i know where i went wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to get the value of the selected city in the change event handler.

In the event handler `this` refers to the changed element, so you can just read the its value

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#city").change(function () {
        var selectedCountry1 = this.value; //or $(this).val()
        //if you want to get the text of the selected option
        var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text(); //find the selected option inside the current select
        alert("You have selected the city- " + selectedCountry1);

    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#parent_cat").change(function () {
        var selectedCountry = this.value; //or $(this).val()
        alert("You have selected the Country - " + selectedCountry);

    });
});
```

---

The problem with your code is `$("option:selected")` returns all the `option` elements which are selected, but when you use the getter `.val()` it will return only the value of the first selected `option` element's value, so you will be getting the same value everywhere.

Comment: hi arun if want to read the both values at time what need to be changed.
can i know pls

Comment: @user3124779 `var city = $("#city").val(); var cat = $("#parent_cat").val()`

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

```
$(this).val();
```

instead of

```
$("option:selected").val();
```